# Can't call array record in second page PHP

Tags: php

I've two page , first page there's an array data and second page I want call array data

Like this

First page index.php

```
    $array_data[]=$array_tmp;
    print_r($array_data); // array can display in this page

    $_SESSION['one'] = $array_data;
```

Second page next.php
I want to call array from first page

```
session_start();

$array = $_SESSION['one'];
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    echo $value;
}

print_r($_SESSION['one'])
```

May I know what's wrong? As array can't display in second page.

Comment: Use session_start()  on index.php.

Comment: you need `session_start()` in `index.php` as well

Comment: yes i did , but still can't

Comment: Is there any error you got. ?

Comment: There's no reason why your code shouldn't be working. Use `session_start()` in the first code snippet if you haven't. Also, a semicolon is missing after `print_r()` statement in snippet 2.

Comment: everything should be good. maybe you have problems with session_start() ? try to look what it return. should return true.

Comment: i dont know .. still can't working ..

Comment: @VladimirKovpak thanks you're right .. no problem with my code ..  my mistake, i wrong  call the session in second page . This thread closed

Comment: for all help thanks so much ..

Answer (score -1):

I think you should change this code `$array = $_SESSION['one'];` to `$array[] = $_SESSION['one'];`. I`m not sure & not tested as well but I think so. Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

You need to start the session if you already have not. Without starting the session, you can't assign value to the session variable. So the first code snippet would be like this:

```
session_start();
$array_data[]=$array_tmp;
print_r($array_data); // array can display in this page

$_SESSION['one'] = $array_data;
```

Second snippet looks fine but the last line is missing a semicolon. It might sound silly, but that can prevent the whole script from running. Here's the code fixed.

```
session_start();

$array = $_SESSION['one'];
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    echo $value;
}
print_r($_SESSION['one']);
```

Post more code if this does not work.